# Redirecting output to output file

Tags: bash, unix

I have an input File that has the following data:

```
one two
three
fish hat
cat hop
```

I have to write the following to an output file

```
one two three
fish hat cat hop
```

Here is my code i have so far

```
#!/bin/bash
#

# input and output files
FILE=$1
FILE2=$2

#checks to see if the input file exists
if  [ -f $FILE ];then
echo "file $FILE  found!"
else
echo "file $FILE does not exist"
exit 1
fi

#check to see if output file is empty
 if [ -s $FILE2 ]; then
echo "$FILE2 already has data!"
exit 1
fi

#Joins every two input lines
while read first; do read second; echo "$firstLine $secondLine";
done < $FILE

 cat $FILE &> $FILE2
```

I get the output file to print to the console however when I use the cat command to display the contents of the output file. It displays the original output file. Can someone point out the mistake that I am making?

Comment: With GNU sed and your example: `sed '1~2{N;s/\n/ /}' file`

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you ask for:

```
cat $file | paste -d ' ' - -
```

And to send the output to file2:

```
cat $file | paste -d ' ' - - > $file2
```

Note: Use lowercase variables, Upper case variables are reserved for environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> done < $FILE
>
>  cat $FILE &> $FILE2
> ```
>
> I get the output file to print to the console however when I use the cat command to display the contents of the output file. It displays the original output file. Can someone point out the mistake that I am making?

The mistakes are that you don't write the output to the output file in the first place and that even if you did, you'd overwrite the output file by the `cat …`; drop the latter and change the line above to:

```
done <$FILE >$FILE2
```